# Amazon KF8 file format specifications

Tags: epub, kindle

I want to generate KF8 without going through the conversion process (My Content --> Epub/Html --> KindleGen/Calibre/Other tool), as I need more control over kf8 file generation. 
The [guidelines document](http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf) & the [format overview](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000729511) can't fulfill the need for specifications.

**Are official KF8 file format specs available?** 
Although I have found some information on links such as http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KF8#The_Format, but want to avoid relying on unofficial/reverse-engineered stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, Amazon hasn't released a complete spec, only the docs you pointed out.